# Responsive Images in Oracle APEX V5.1.1 - Universal Theme

Tags: oracle-apex, responsive, responsive-images

I am using Oracle APEX v5.1.1 - Universal Theme (Desktop application).

Currently building a desktop application using v5.1.1 + Universal Theme, by where I need to have an image as the landing page. On the desktop front, this is fine but this application will also be viewed on a tablet as well as a mobile device.

With the Universal Theme or perhaps a built-in template or class, how can I achieve the responsiveness of the Universal Theme when it comes to viewing this landing page image on a mobile device, i.e. how can I make the image responsive as well?

Not sure if I need to somehow use media queries and load in a different size image on my landing page, based on device being used.

Comment: Universal Theme  itself comes with responsive nature hence it will automate display accordingly. Please use "display image"  field to show image on page. Hope this will you!